# About change $\Delta t$ to proper time for the the relativitistic momentum

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, vectors

The problem that we use $p=mv$ in all frames will cause the momentum is not conserved in all frames, and in my book, it is said that since $p=m\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$, this $\Delta t$ causes the problem.  Thus in order to make momentum conserved, we use the proper time $(\Delta t=\gamma \Delta \tau)$ and substitute $\Delta t$ by $\Delta \tau$,
we define relativistic momentum $p=\gamma mv $

However, I don't understand why this $\Delta t$ causes problem, and change $\Delta t$ to proper time. Why we don't change $\Delta x$ to proper length?

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Can you provide your sources? In 3D view, you simply use lengths and times measured in your frame, but you need to include objects kinetic energy in the form of relativistic mass. It is mass that is rationale for adding $\gamma$ not time dilation.

Comment: To see why conservation of momentum leads to relativistic mass, you can surely google the derivation, like https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2017/09/12/derivation-of-relativistic-mass/